# Intellij-idea - Giving error when extending Groovy Class

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, groovy

I am trying to extend a groovy class in Grails application using idea intellij but I am getting this error. The application runs successfully but it is highlighting it as red. I am using `grails 3.2.6` with `gradle 3.3`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that IntelliJ for whatever reason thinks that the base class JwtService has an abstract method `on` which you have not implemented.

Might be worth navigating (right-click -> go to declaration) to the base class and checking that IntelliJ resolves the base class to the class you think it should be resolving to (I assume it's supposed to resolve to [JwtService](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/1.5.1/docs/gapi/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/JwtService.html)?)

Comment: I have checked this is not the reason. Intellij is going to expected JwtSerivice class